# console.log not working for jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Here is my jQuery at the bottom of html page:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#login').click(function() {
            var co_id = $('#companies').val();
            console.log(co_id); 
        });
    });
    </script>
```

When I type this jQuery into the console, then type `co_id` it works, but when I run this in browser and choose a company and click the correct button, and I would assume when I type `co_id` into chrome browser console, it would show my option value? But it is coming back as:

```
>co_id
ReferenceError: co_id is not defined
```

Here is html:

```
<select name="" id="companies">
    <option value="--">--</option>
    <option value="1">Company</option>
    <option value="2">Company2</option>
    <option value="3">Company3</option>
    <option value="68">Company4</option>
    <option value="69">Company5</option>
    <option value="70">Company6</option>
</select><input id="login" type="submit" value="Login">
```

Comment: True, but shouldn't I still see 'co_id' come back as defined each time I type it? It is still declaring it as a string...I have actually already tried it with your method and it still comes back undefined.

Comment: If you want to see `co_id` in the console, you have to define it as a global, so **outside** `$(document).ready(...)` function.

Answer (score 6):

Don't write code if you set the src attribute.

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#login').click(function() {
        var co_id = $('#companies').val();
        console.log(co_id);   
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Lol, wish I could give you the answer. I have to wait 7 minutes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that the Chrome console is always running in the global scope but `co_id` is scoped to the closure.

To inspect the values you have 3 options:

1. Declare co_id to be in the global scope. To do this simply remove the `var` in front of the variable name and add `var co_id` in the global scope. I don't recommend this, inevitably you'll forget to make the scope local again and you'll end up with a lot of global variables. They can be a source of a lot of fun bugs.
2. Change the `console.log()` to actually output the variable content like this: `console.log(co_id);`.
3. The best solution: Set a break point in the function by clicking on the line number in the script pane.